# filter icon is too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In some interfaces the user is presented with search box with an adjacent sort/filter icon (up and down arrows), sometimes this icon is accompanied by a Cancel button.

The sort/filter icon is a very small touch target, especially when the Cancel button is adjacent.  I accidentally hit Cancel when I was aiming for Sort/Filter.

[image: screenshot of app with sort + cancel buttons]

Apple specifies in their [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf) (warning huge PDF) that the minimum touch target be no smaller than 44 x 44px.  I could be mistaken but I believe this touch target is smaller than that.

Incidentally the "Cancel" button is underlined in this screen shot because I have modified the Phone's Accessibility Settings as follows:  Button Shapes -- ON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. The sort button was already 44 tall, but it was definitely not 44 wide.

As of version **0.1.58**, it should be easier to tap.